# Less code in case statement PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement

is there a way to write less code ( factorize) following statement.
In my case I have webform_client_form_AKEY where the AKEY var changes and my var passed in the uri ( ?C= = 1...).
Thank you

```
switch ($form_id)
{
case 'webform_client_form_9944':
    $form['#action'] = url('section/client-tool-box/appointment?c=1');          
    break;
case 'webform_client_form_9883':
    $form['#action'] = url('section/client-tool-box/appointment?c=2'); 
    break;
case 'webform_client_form_9884':
    $form['#action'] = url('section/client-tool-box/appointment?c=3');          
    break;
...
}
```

Comment: Since there is nothing associated from cases to url's ... that's the best alternative.

Answer (score 3):

Use a 'dictionary' approach:

```
$array = array(
    "webform_client_form_9944" => "1",
    "webform_client_form_9883" => "2",
    "webform_client_form_9884" => "3"
);

if (array_key_exists($array, $form_id))
    $form['#action'] = url('section/client-tool-box/appointment?c=' . $array[$form_id]);
else
    $form['#action'] = ""; // default
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$urls = array(
  'webform_client_form_9944' => 'section/client-tool-box/appointment?c=1',
  'webform_client_form_9883' => 'section/client-tool-box/appointment?c=2',
   ...
);

$form['#action'] = url($urls[$form_id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya :

```
$cat = 0; //0 : default cat
switch ($form_id) {
   case 'webform_client_form_9944': $cat = 1; break;
   case 'webform_client_form_9883': $cat = 2; break;
   case 'webform_client_form_9884': $cat = 3; break;
   ...
}
$form['#action'] = url('section/client-tool-box/appointment?c='.$cat);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way

```
$form_id= 'webform_client_form_9944';
$cons = 'webform_client_form_';

switch($form_id){
    case $cons.'9944':
        $c = 1;
        break;
    case $cons.'9883':
        $c = 2;
        break;
}
$form['#action'] = url('section/client-tool-box/appointment?c='.$c);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping the "form_id" to "c" mapping in an array? That makes it much easier to maintain, I guess. Also, there is no more duplicated code:

```
<?php
$form_id = 'webform_client_form_9944';

$forms = array(
    '9944' => '1',
    '9883' => '2',
    '9884' => '3'
);

$id = str_replace('webform_client_form_', '', $form_id);

if (isset ($forms[$id])) {
    $form['#action'] = url('section/client-tool-box/appointment?c=3');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that writing less code here actually matters. But I guess code would be easier to maintain if you abstract data out:

```
// Untested
$id_to_c = array(
    9944 => 1,
    9883 => 2,
    9884 => 3,
);
if( preg_match('^webform_client_form_(\\d)$', $form_id, $matches) ){
    if( array_keys_exists($matches[1], $id_to_c) ){
        $form['#action'] = url('section/client-tool-box/appointment?c=' . rawurlencode($id_to_c[$matches[1]]));   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$formid = end(explode('_', $form_id));
$map = array(9944=>1, 9883=>2, 9844=>3, ...);

$form['#action'] = url("section/client-tool-box/appointment?c={$map['webform_client_form_'.$map[$formid]}");
```